# How do I use PyInstaller to make packaged applications smaller

Tags: pyinstaller

How do you make packaged generated applications smaller?

I type in the terminal of Windows

```
PS C:\Users\Lenovo-pc> PyInstaller -w 123.py
```

But the package is huge, and the following modules are mainly imported

```
import time,threading,itertools
from tkinter import Label,Tk,Button,Text,END,PhotoImage,Entry,RAISED
from random import shuffle,choice
from datetime import datetime
from openpyxl import load_workbook
```

How do I make the resulting executable smaller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you can't do much about that, because PyInstaller would bring each dependency beside your application output. On the other side sometimes it brings unnecessary modules with your output which should be ignored.

For a small executable output you can do two things:

1. Always use `virtualenv` to buildup your app. This would remove unnecessary packages that you already installed on your main Python library. So they will be ignored on the current build.
2. According to [this](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/usage.html#using-upx) using a compression decrease your output executable significantly.

   > UPX is a free utility available for most operating systems. UPX
   >   compresses executable files and libraries, making them smaller,
   >   sometimes much smaller. UPX is available for most operating systems
   >   and can compress a large number of executable file formats. See the
   >   UPX home page for downloads, and for the list of supported executable
   >   formats.

So bring up a `virtualenv` install your external dependencies and then install UPX from [here](https://upx.github.io/) and use `--upx-dir` to pass UPX dir.

Comment: If I use upx, the program won't work on other computers, and it will show me what's missing

Comment: No, it won't there is **no need** to have UPX installed on target machines.